# The Internet connection in my Ubuntu seems slow

Tags: command-line, wireless

I have recently encountered an error where my Wifi wont work on my Ubuntu desktop. It is working fine on every other device. The wifi worked fine for some time at full speed, but now it doesn't work

I tried a few solutions from online but nothing seems to work.

Here is a screenshot of the speed I am getting.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You've provided few details; you mention Ubuntu Desktop, but not what release of that product. Ubuntu Desktop used to set the *default* kernel stack choice by the ISO used for install; with recent releases always default to HWE kernel stack - but we don't know what release you're using, nor what it was installed with thus cannot say. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS recently switched from 5.19 to 6.2 if using HWE kernel stack; thus returning to GA maybe a quick fix - but you gave no specifics as to your release or kernel stack being used.  You mention an error; but didn't provide that error message.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the answer . I have a Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS version installed. However i dont how to change it from HWE kernel to GA, please guide me through it

Comment: If you were fully upgraded; a 22.04 system now reports itself as 22.04.3 and uses the 6.2 HWE kernel stack (*as this is recent; some mirrors if behind, may not have rolled those changes out; your 22.04.2 shows you're behind on fixes so I'd upgrade your system first!*).  Read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details (*both GA & HWE can co-exist; thus why it says to TEST FIRST & remove the other stack when/if happy; ie. it's optional; though some closed-source kernel modules can prevent this*). This is a Q&A site so add additional details (22.04.2) to your question please.

Comment: @guiverc tried going through what you mentioned, but couldn't find the right solution or update. The Kernel i am on (checked using uname -r) is 5.19. I could furnish more detail if you ask me to if you mention what command to run.